# Why I am getting this "too many indices for tensor of dimension 1" error and how I can solve it?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

for this piece of code:

```
# bounding box to tensor
boxes = torch.as_tensor(boxes, dtype=torch.float32)
# area of the bounding boxes
area = (boxes[:, 3] - boxes[:, 1]) * (boxes[:, 2] - boxes[:, 0])
# no crowd instances
```

On the compiler the error shows:

```
line 80, in __getitem__
area = (boxes[:, 3] - boxes[:, 1]) * (boxes[:, 2] - boxes[:, 0])
IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`boxes` only has one axis (it is a "tensor of dimension 1"), so you have to reshape it to have two axes before accessing it with two indices. The following example would work: `boxes.reshape(-1,4)[:,3]`. But you should `print(boxes)` first to better understand it and what kind of reshaping makes sense.